# VB.NET open connection to Postgres

Tags: .net, vb.net, postgresql

I am working on a project that require to connect to Postgresql, I have tried this code below:

```
Public Module Main
Dim _desktop As Desktop = Agent.Desktop

Public Sub Main(args As IDictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=postgres;server=127.0.0.1;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=9.4;User ID=postgres;password=12345678;"

    conn.Open()
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Connected To PostGres", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
End Module
```

But I have the problem `Type 'Odbc.OdbcConnection' is not defined.`. Is there anyone can help me to resolve problem? The error indicates that I has not imported the dependency, but I dont't know right way to import.

Comment: Every type in the .NET Framework has a topic dedicated to it in the documentation. Those topics include what assembly the type is declared in and what namespace it's a member of. In order to access the type, you must reference that assembly. In order to refer to the type, you need to specify the namespace, either explicitly or via an import.

Comment: did u add reference to related dlls??

Comment: I have add this line `Imports System.Data.Odbc` to import Odbc, but I still get an error `Data source not found and no default driver specified`. What am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you :

```
 Dim MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
MyCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=database_name;server=127.0.0.1;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=dis
 able;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=postgres;password=password;"

  MyCon.Open()
    If mCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Connected To PostGres", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
    End If
```

Make sure you type the correct IP,username and password.But before everything, please install required [drivers](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)